# Replace list of permutations with getSymbols data in R

Tags: r, time-series, permutation, quantmod

I downloaded some stock data:

```
require("quantmod")
s <- c("AAPL", "ADBE", "ADI", "ADP", "ADSK") 
e <- new.env()
getSymbols(s, src='yahoo',  from='2015-01-10',  env = e )

#get closing prices
close <- do.call(merge, eapply(e, function(x) Cl(x)))
```

I found all the pairs of symbol names:

```
#find all the pairwise permutations
perm<-combn(s,2)
perm
[,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]  [,9]   [,10] 
[1,] "AAPL" "AAPL" "AAPL" "AAPL" "ADBE" "ADBE" "ADBE" "ADI" "ADI"  "ADP" 
[2,] "ADBE" "ADI"  "ADP"  "ADSK" "ADI"  "ADP"  "ADSK" "ADP" "ADSK" "ADSK"
```

I'd like to take the "close" data for each name and replace for each pair group of "perm" to be able to analyse the pairs later.

Comment: why was this q downvoted so that I may better ask the question next time?

Comment: I wasn't a downvoter, but I would say that one possible reason for the downvotes is that you have asked for your data to be reshaped but you have not indicated how you wanted it reshaped -- the last sentence doesn't specify exactly how you want the data stored. Your question could have been improved by showing a small example of how you wanted it stored, perhaps by manually combining one of the pairs.

Comment: thanks that's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to get a list of data frames, one for each pair, you could try:

```
dfs <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(perm)), function(x) close[,paste0(perm[,x], ".Close")])
```

Now you can get the 2-column data frames for each pair with `dfs[[1]]`, `dfs[[2]]`, etc. You can perform statistical analyses on each pair using the `lapply` function. Here's a simple example where you get the summary of every paired data frame:

```
lapply(dfs, summary)
```